# Facebook API post: How to get larger thumbnail?

Tags: php, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, image-size

There is this new thumbnail view on Facebook (see image beneath this text). But every command or property I tried, I never get this when posting with the api...

This is how my post event looks like right now:

```
 $status = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array('access_token' =>     $page_access_token, 'fields' => 'picture.height(960).width(1833)', 'message' => $text, 'icon' => 'http://www.renoi.de/images/lg.jpg', 'link' => $link, 'name' => $title, 'user_generated' => 'true', 'images[0]' => $pic2, 'source' => $pic2, 'height' => '960', 'width' => '1833'));
```

And this is the og:image line that fb takes for manual posting:

```
  <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $og_image; ?>" />
```

Please believe me that $og_image and $pic2 are exactly the same url, none thumbnail, full quality, far beyond 720p.

I would highly appreciate any input on this matter that is not "use ?type=large" or sth. like that.

[image]

Comment: create new tag "thumbnail" needs at least 1500 points. gtfo! -.-

Comment: According to some discussions in the FB developer group it seems that only posts made via FB.ui (or directly on Facebook) get the larger images at the moment – but posts made via API don’t. (They seem to appear large on the target wall, but still in small in the feed.)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what the problem is. So there’s no workaround? :(

Comment: http://lightningsoul.com/media/img/screenshot/fb_js_api_big_thumbnail.png
So I just tested the FB JS SDK with FB.ui and a redirection URL and both do not use big thumnails (img is 1080p!) ... what now? :(

Comment: Have you found any trough the api?

Comment: What do you mean with 'found any'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed with the design update immenent on the servers (I am using a beta server, so I am seeing things earlier).

Finally, thank you Facebook!

[image: thumbnails in full width in fb api posts]

Comment: Can you tell how to do such thumbnails?

Comment: It is automatically pulled if your orignal image source is big enough for it to generate a larger thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

So now that it is IMPOSSIBLE to do this with the API I am using a workaround as frustrating as it may be. It is a share button system on the left of my content.

The result on facebook can be seen here (actually pretty cool because it shifts more results into each other): 
http://lightningsoul.com/media/img/screenshot/likes_on_facebook_share_content.png

```
// Will get your actual browser address and share it

<?php     $thisadress = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>

 <div id="fblikem">
      <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
      <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
      <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1" addthis:url="<?php echo $thisadress; ?>"></a>
      <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2" addthis:url="<?php echo $thisadress; ?>"></a>
      <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3" addthis:url="<?php echo $thisadress; ?>"></a>
      <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4" addthis:url="<?php echo $thisadress; ?>"></a>
      <a class="addthis_button_compact" addthis:url="<?php echo $thisadress; ?>"></a>
      <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style" addthis:url="<?php echo $thisadress; ?>"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
//And the CSS to make it stay on the left side of your content (centered 1280px wide)
 #fblikem_vertical
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: -715px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Hopefully FB will fix this at some point. If so I will, of course, inform you on here.

Answer (score -1):

This code could work perfect for me:

```
 $appid = 'xxxxxxx';
 $appsecret = 'xxxxxxxx';
 $pageId = $pageid;    
 $msg = $title;

 $title = $facebook_title;

 $uri = $url;

 $desc = $intro_text;

 $pic = $todir;

 $action_name = 'Go to 1tvnews';

 $action_link = $url;

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => $appid,

 'secret' => $appsecret,

 'cookie' => false,
 ));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

// Contact Facebook and get token

 if ($user) {

 // you're logged in, and we'll get user acces token for posting on the wall

 try {

 $page_info = $facebook->api("/$pageId?fields=access_token");

 if (!empty($page_info['access_token'])) {

 $attachment = array(

 'access_token' => $page_info['access_token'],

  'message'=> $msg,

'from' => $appid,

'to' => $pageid,

'caption' =>'1tvnews.af', 


'name' =>$facebook_title ,

'link' => $uri,

'picture' => $todir2,
            'description' => $intro_text
 );

$status = $facebook->api("/$pageId/feed", "post", $attachment);

 } 
else
 {
 $status = 'No access token recieved';
 }
 } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
 error_log($e);
 $user = null;
 }
 } 
else 
{
 // you're not logged in, the application will try to log in to get a access token

header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 
'photo_upload,user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,manage_pages'))}");
 }
```