# Get Larger Image From Facebook Post?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently getting the newsfeed of a Facebook user. Currently, I can only retrieve thumbnail images that are associated with links, rather than the full-size image. Does anyone know how to get a larger image?

I've looked at the following posts and tried their solutions; however, the posts seem outdated and the facebook graph api seems to have changed since then:

[Facebook Graph API Change: Picture type (size) no longer working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982276/facebook-graph-api-change-picture-type-size-no-longer-working)

[Facebook API post: How to get larger thumbnail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352190/facebook-api-post-how-to-get-larger-thumbnail)

Please note that I'm on the me/home edge, so the answer below returns an error. See comments below.

my code is:

```
params.putString("fields","id,actions,application,caption,created_time,description,from,link,message,message_tags,"
        + "name,object_id,picture,place,source,status_type,story,updated_time,type,status_type,story,to,type,"
        + "updated_time,with_tags");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I came to this solution:

1) find the URL of the larger image (see code below)

2) get bitmap from URL and add to application UI.

The code mentioned above:

```
private String getRealURL(String smallURL){
   if (smallURL.contains("url=http")){
       String[] pieces = smallURL.split("url=");
       pieces[1].replace("%2F", "//");
       pieces[1].replace("%3A", ":");
       Log.e("RealURL1:", pieces[1]);
       return pieces[1];           
   }
   else{
       StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
       stringBuilder.setLength(0);
       stringBuilder.append("https://graph.facebook.com/");
       stringBuilder.append(item.getObjectID());
       stringBuilder.append("/picture?type=normal&access_token=");
       stringBuilder.append(Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken());
       Log.e("RealURL2:", stringBuilder.toString());
       return stringBuilder.toString();
   }
}
```

Comment: I will Use if i need further.

Answer (score 1):

Change to this:

```
params.putString("fields","id,actions,application,caption,created_time,description,from,link,message,message_tags,"
        + "name,object_id,full_picture,place,source,status_type,story,updated_time,type,status_type,story,to,type,"
        + "updated_time,with_tags");
```

Here `picture.height(1000)` will give you a large image. and you can put your own required size but it is not supported in `me/home` i have searched a lot.

For Testing purposre use this link :[Facebook graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).

Comment: I just tried that and my app crashed... hmmm... (more details to come)

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "message": "Subfields are not supported by picture", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 2500
  }
}

Comment: I'm on the me/home edge

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this field ?field=full_picture instead of picture.

Answer (score 0):

?field=full_picture is the only way to get it to work now. I have been searching everywhere, and finally found the answer here. picture field doesn't support subfields any more so you can't use picture.width.height any more